# python how can i read gzip file line by line that from http requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests, streaming, gzip

Now my situation is this. I request gzip file by requests module(it's size is big so i use stream option).Unzip this gzfile, it is dictonary.txt. And then I want to read this string while reading gz.file (http get). like this

```
with r.get(url,stream='true') as res:
 #gz file is big so read by iter_content
 for chunk in res.iter_content(chunck_size=512)
 #I get an error in the below part, I want read str Line
 extracted = gzip.decompress(chunk)
            for line in extracted.split(b'\n'):
                line = line.decode()
```

Comment: what's the result you get? Why would you expect?

Comment: gzip original file is dictonary.txt. so i want to read it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import gzip

with requests.get(url,stream=True) as res:
    extracted = gzip.decompress(res.content)
    for line in extracted.split(b'\n'):
        line = line.decode()
```

Comment: this will download the entire file, the OP wanted to go chunk my chunk